# Computing Shannon-Weiner biodiversity index using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, r, land-survey, marine

I wonder if anybody has some experience in calculating biodiversity index (such as Shannon-Weiner) using QGIS?

I am also interested for similar experiences using R scripts within QGIS.

The analysis will use species count from individual stations of marine scientific surveys.

I have in mind to calculate the Shannon index of species diversity for each station of the sampling survey and then to "allocate" the average index within each cell of a vector grid or by interpolation in the Area of interest.

I wonder if anyone has experience in doing this using a spatial query (providing  stations and vector grid are stored in a sqlite database)?

Comment: **(a)** I am not really sure how this is thematically related to GIS as you calculate this index on the counts and not the point shapefile **(b)** You can easily calculate it using existing r-packages like `vegan`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. What I am looking for is something similar to what is in [link] (http://code.nicholas.duke.edu/projects/mget/export/1090/MGET/Trunk/PythonPackage/dist/TracOnlineDocumentation/Documentation/PythonReference/Method_GeoEco.SpatialAnalysis.Diversity.SpeciesDiversity.CalculateDiversityIndexForArcGISPolygons.html?format=raw) where the index is calculated by predefined zones.

Comment: I echo @Curlew, there are functions in R to calculate diversity metrics. All you are talking about is aggregating the metric by group. To do this just assign your polygon IDS to the species observations and pass the data to vegan::diversity using tapply. This will give you diversity by group.

Comment: Thank you @JeffreyEvans and others, I will follow your advice in relation to vegan package.